# Auto-sizing div elements

Tags: asp.net, html, autosize

I'm doing some work cleaning up an asp.net web application, dropping some html code into asp.net but I'm running into some formatting issues. I have a Site.Master page that all my content pages inherit from. I have a couple of `div` elements nested within each other on this page, wherein i have an asp control into which I drop all the contents from my content pages. The problem is that my `div` containers don't auto-size though and thus the contents overflow. I don't do a lot of web development so I need some help on this one.

HTML (Site.Master)

```
<body>
    ...
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header>
        <!-- Stuff -->
        </header>

        <div id="content-wrapper">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="maincontent" runat="server" />
        </div>
        <!-- More Stuff -->
    </div> <!-- End wrapper -->
    <!-- Even More Stuff -->
 </body>
```

CSS

```
#content-wrapper{
width:98%;  
height:100%;
margin:0 auto;
min-height:800px;
background:white;

-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0.50em;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0.50em;

-moz-border-radius-bottomright:0.50em;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0.50em;

border-bottom-right-radius:0.50em;
border-bottom-left-radius:0.50em;
}

.wrapper {
min-height: 100%;   
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;   
margin: 0 auto -4em;
}
```

Someone else wrote the html and css, which is not something I'm too familiar with, and I'm just dropping it into an application, so I'm a little lost on all this formatting business. To reiterate, the content that I drop into the ASP placeholder is overflowing the "wrapper" and "content-wrapper" containers. The HTML files are good though so somehow i'm messing it up as I cut it up to put in the application.

When I say overflow I mean that the content spills out of its container. See here for an example: http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/. The overflow is `visible`

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "overflowing" ?

Answer (score 0):

The Doctype declaration was messing up the formatting.

Changed it from:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

to:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

and I no longer had my issue.